# How to correct: The economic situation of the country today is almost same as we experienced in the early 1960’s

Tags: grammar, as

I'm supposed to correct the following:

The economic situation of the country today is almost same as we experienced in the early 1960’s.

The answer suggests, "almost as the same as that."

Is this correct? I thought "as the same as" is grammatically wrong.

Comment: Apart from the missing article, your sentence is one that many native speakers would say, but an editor focusing on the grammar would correct it,saying that you need two nominal comparands, "economic situation of the country today" versus "*what* we experienced" or "*that (which)* we experienced" . The clause *we experienced in the early 1960s* is not a valid nominal, strictly speaking.

Comment: The counterargument could be that "the same" is a subject complement, and it is complemented by the content-clause "as we experienced in the early 1960s".

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be an error in the suggested answer! "almost as the same as" is almost certainly not correct.

I would probably say:

- "...is almost the same as the one we experienced...", or
- "...is almost the same as that which we experienced..."
- "...is almost as [adjective] as [the one/that which] we experienced..."